# Two error happening in my scripts need helpe

Tags: powershell

I got two problem with my script. 
First:

```
[xml]$Contents = C:\ScriptDumpFiles\RssCalendarExtract\ConnectFeed.xml
```

But everytime I run in, it tries to open the xml file in notepad. When I run it in my machine it was able to put data content of xml to my variable. Does version have to do with this?

second:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://hiddenurl.com/calendar/export.php?type=rss2' -OutFile C:\scripts\ConnectFeed.xml
```

but it give me an error:

> "You are using an outdated web browser. This website has features that
>   require a modern web browser. Please update your web browser to
>   improve your experience and for better security."

Note I am trying to get data from an RSS feed. Its working on my machine but when I tried to run on our server both error shows up. Should I update my browser or my powershell version?

Comment: `C:\ScriptDumpFiles\RssCalendarExtract\ConnectFeed.xml` -> `Get-Content 'C:\ScriptDumpFiles\RssCalendarExtract\ConnectFeed.xml'`. You have to run a command that will actually read the file. `Get-Content` can do that.

Comment: Thank I was able to read the file. Not sure why it was working on my machine and in the server it opens it instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @AdminOfThings stated in the above comment (in the OP) you've to fetch the content via the [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) cmdlet. Therefore change the following code from:

```
C:\ScriptDumpFiles\RssCalendarExtract\ConnectFeed.xml
```

to:

```
Get-Content 'C:\ScriptDumpFiles\RssCalendarExtract\ConnectFeed.xml'
```